# coding multivariate response in R Party Package

Tags: r, machine-learning, party

I am looking to do multivariate prediction using the party package in R (Party package documentation below)

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/party/party.pdf

I however, cannot figure out how to do multivariate prediction (multiple response variables). It says that it can do it, and I try this:

```
f <-cbind(A,B,C~shopping_pt+n_A_0)

model_1 <- ctree(f, data= train)
```

But that produces the following error:

> Error in [<-(*tmp*, nas, drop = FALSE, value = 0) : (subscript) logical subscript too long

The documentation says it supports multivariate... but doesn't suggest how one can write the syntax correctly, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following syntax:

```
ctree(A + B + C ~ shopping_pt + n_A_0, data=train)
```

Comment: It does not appear that, that works. I am using this, 
'mvpart(data.matrix(master3_imputed.train[,72:78])~ shopping_pt+n_A_0, data=train)' and it appears to be working, but it is a very cumersome way to do it, I prefer to specify variables. I would like your method to work... is it possible there is a variation? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try the package `partykit`

Check the sample below where it shows how you can code the multivariate response for the Conditional Inference Tree

```
### multivariate responses
airq2 <- ctree(Ozone + Temp ~ ., data = airq)
airq2
plot(airq2)
```